# UnknownHostException on accessing cloud server through httpclient but works fine on chrome browser

Tags: java, httpclient, apache-httpclient-4.x, apache-commons-httpclient

I am working on a testing tool which fires api's directly to server and validate its response.
it was working fine until the application is moved to a remote cloud server.

I am using apache httpclient in my tool as below.

```
CloseableHttpClient client = HttpClients.createDefault();
HttpGet get = new HttpGet(url);
get.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
HttpResponse response = client.execute(get);
```

Now i am getting

```
java.net.UnknownHostException: This is usually a temporary error during hostname resolution and means that the local server did not receive a response from an authoritative server ("server url")
at java.net.Inet4AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Native Method)
at java.net.InetAddress$2.lookupAllHostAddr(InetAddress.java:928)
at java.net.InetAddress.getAddressesFromNameService(InetAddress.java:1323)
at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(InetAddress.java:1276)
at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1192)
at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1126)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.SystemDefaultDnsResolver.resolve(SystemDefaultDnsResolver.java:45)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:112)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.BasicHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(BasicHttpClientConnectionManager.java:325)
at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:381)
at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:237)
at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:185)
at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:89)
at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:111)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:185)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:83)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:108)
at RESTAPI.HttpClientTester.main(HttpClientTester.java:62)
```

I get the same error after setting preferipv4 as true.

```
  System.setProperty("java.net.preferIPv4Stack" , "true");
```

I am confused because, it works fine from chrome browser and SOAP UI tool. 
i have been digging this for 3 days and searched every related questions/articles. still couldn't solve it.
What have i done wrong?. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm not too sure on what the problem is, but if you go into terminal and type `nslookup <url>`, what do you get?

Comment: Got this on nslookup "*** <local server> can't find <server url>: Server failed"

Comment: @MarioIshac+ url and hostname (or domainname) are different things. nslookup only works on (hostnames that are) domainnames; try `nslookup $hostname`. But nslookup only uses DNS, whereas programs like Java also use other kinds of resolution depending on your OS and sometimes environment; Rob: what OS? If Unix, try `getent hosts $hostname` and/or `getent ahosts $hostname`

Comment: @dave since the api runs as client.. it is in windows. yeah i used hostname only in nslookup and got server failed error. can i use any other DNS servers?

Comment: Java on Windows uses the Winsock (i.e. OS) routine getaddrinfo, which uses an internal cache plus the DNS servers currently defined in Windows, which usually come from DHCP but can be manually configured on each active network interface. The traditional option for user control is the network control panel (which has gone through variations in name in different versions of Windows) but there are also netsh and (TTBOMK) powershell interfaces.